# How to encrypt Blowfish/CBC/PKCS5Padding, comparing encryption in PHP and Java

Tags: java, php, encryption

I am trying to encrypt text, the problem is I have two different encrypted values in PHP and Java.

Expected output should be the same in PHP and Java.

Is there a way to achieve this and work on this code if ever there are any problems?

Here are the encrypted result:

PHP Code:

```
<?php
$cipher = 'BF-CBC';

$key = 'SECRETKEY';

$iv = "abcdefgh";

$opts = OPENSSL_ZERO_PADDING;

$plaintext = "Text";

if (strlen($plaintext) % 8) {
    $plaintext = str_pad($plaintext, strlen($plaintext) + 8 - strlen($plaintext) % 8, "\0");
}

$chiperRaw = openssl_encrypt($plaintext, $cipher, $key, $opts, $iv);

$ciphertext = trim(base64_encode($chiperRaw));

echo($ciphertext);

?>
```

Java Code:

```
private static final String ALGORITHM = "Blowfish";
private static final String MODE = "Blowfish/CBC/PKCS5Padding";
private static final String IV = "abcdefgh";
private static final String Key = "SECRETKEY";

public static String encrypt(String value) throws NoSuchPaddingException, NoSuchAlgorithmException, InvalidAlgorithmParameterException, InvalidKeyException, IllegalBlockSizeException, BadPaddingException {
    SecretKeySpec secretKeySpec = new SecretKeySpec(Key.getBytes(), ALGORITHM);
    Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance(MODE);
    cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, secretKeySpec, new IvParameterSpec(IV.getBytes()));
    byte[] values = cipher.doFinal(value.getBytes());
    return Base64.encodeToString(values, Base64.DEFAULT);
}
```

Result

```
PHP: 83kZpBbrQT4= 

Java: YBSmeMNPSjw=
```

Output should be:

```
PHP: YBSmeMNPSjw= 
Java: YBSmeMNPSjw=
```

Comment: @shingo - hello, you are referring to PHP right? how can I sort it? how about the base64 encode? can you please show me pseudo or a code itself please?

Comment: @shingo - i've updated my code above, please check? still getting the same result: `83kZpBbrQT4=`

Comment: @shingo - ive update my code but still getting same result, pls check sir

Answer (score 0):

Refer to this bug: https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=72362, you can use an undocumented option **OPENSSL_DONT_ZERO_PAD_KEY** to solve this problem.

```
openssl_encrypt("Text","BF-CBC","SECRETKEY",OPENSSL_DONT_ZERO_PAD_KEY,"abcdefgh");
```

Otherwise you need manually pad the key up to a rational size.

```
openssl_encrypt("Text","BF-CBC","SECRETKEYSECRETKEY",0,"abcdefgh");
```